# Regular expression for validating numeric values

Tags: c#, regex

I current have the following regular expression to accept any numeric value that is seven digits

`^\d{7}`

How do I improve it so it will accept numeric values that are seven or ten digits?

Pass: 0123456, 1234567, 0123456789, 123467890
Fail: 123456, 12345678, 123456789

Comment: What language are you using? Not all regex are equal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution is this:

```
^\d{7}(\d{3})?$
```

There are at least two things to note with this solution:

- In a unicode context `\d` may match far more than you intended (for example foreign characters that are digits in other non-Latin languages).
- This regular expression contains a capturing group. You probably don't want that. You can fix this by changing it to a non-capturing group `(?: ... )`.

So for these reasons you may want to use this slightly longer expression instead:

```
^[0-9]{7}(?:[0-9]{3})?$
```

Here's a little testbed in C# so that you can see it works:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
{
    string input = new string('0', i);
    bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(input, "^[0-9]{7}(?:[0-9]{3})?$");
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString().PadLeft(2) + ": " + isMatch);
}
```

Result:

```
 0: False
 1: False
 2: False
 3: False
 4: False
 5: False
 6: False
 7: True
 8: False
 9: False
10: True
11: False
```

Comment: The regex pattern `^[0-9]{7}(?:[0-9]{3})?$` worked for every scenario

Comment: @Michael Kniskern: Great! This question was actually more difficult than it first appeared to be. All three posters initially posted an answer which appeared to be correct but was actually wrong! Even the voters did not notice the errors, upvoting the wrong solutions.

Comment: @Mark.  Thanks for your effort.  I feel like every time I enter the world of regular expressions, I am playing a dangerous game.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: This is wrong, but I'm going to undelete it and leave it around for reference purposes, since the upvotes suggest people thought it was right. The correct solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908527/regular-expression-for-validating-numeric-values/2908537#2908537)

---

I think just:

```
^\d{7}\d{3}?
```

Comment: @Mark You mean because it doesn't have a trailing `$`? I left it out because the OP did, but yes, technically :)

Comment: Yes, but it matches the original regex's "looseness". :)

Comment: @Mark It does if you're doing whole-string matching

Comment: I want '12345678' to fail.  It can only accept numeric values that are 7 or ten digits in length.

Comment: All my comments on this post were incorrect so I've deleted them, sorry for the confusion! However I was right that this regular expression is not going to work. I've tested it and it doesn't do what the poster wants, even when taking into account whole-string matching.

Comment: In `\d{3}?` the `?` turns the `{3}` into a reluctant quantifier--in other words, it has no effect.  `^\d{7}\d{3}?` matches any string that starts with ten digits.

Answer (score 2):

Why not a literal interpretation of what you're looking for:

```
^\d{7}|\d{10}$
```

Comment: Except that won't work quite right either, because that's literally `^\d{7}` or `\d{10}$`.  You need to add a a non-capturing group in there, like `^(?:\d{7}|\d{10})$`.